# Anybody know the Reference block name for the Footer->Miscellaneous HTML

Tags: magento2.3, layout, xml, page-layouts

Within Content->Design->Configuration->Theme->Footer->Miscellaneous HTML I have added some HTML and it works correctly

However, I use a popup and it also displays at the bottom of the popup window

Through the pop-ups Layout.xml I would like to remove the Miscellaneous HTML using something like

```
<referenceBlock name="XXXXXXXXXX" remove="true"/>
```

Can anyone please give me the referenceBlock name for the Miscellaneous HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block is called `absolute_footer`, see `magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` where the block is created:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="absolute_footer" template="Magento_Theme::html/absolute_footer.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Hero, thank you.  I couldn't find it